# Terraform AWS-EC2 security groups

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm quite busy with trying to learn more about Terraform but I'm having one problem that I have no clue on how to work-around/fix.

The problem is as follows, in my script I am generating an ec2 instance (AWS) with a couple of side things like en EIP and a security group from a module, which is all working fine. But I cannot figure out how to attach the security group to the machine, now it's being created and that's it.

The code is as follows:

```
data "aws_ami" "latest" {
  most_recent = true
  owners = [ "self"] 

    filter {
      name = "name"
      values = [ lookup(var.default_ami, var.ami) ]
    }
}

module "aws_security_group" {
  source = "./modules/services/Security groups/"
  server_port = 443
}

resource "aws_instance" "test-ec2deployment" {
  ami                           = data.aws_ami.latest.id
  instance_type                 = var.instance_type
  subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
  availability_zone             = var.availability_zone
  associate_public_ip_address   = var.public_ip
  
  root_block_device {
    volume_type                 = "gp2"
    volume_size                 = 60
    delete_on_termination       = true
  }
  
   tags = {
    Name                        = "Testserver2viaTerraform"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "ip" {
  instance = aws_instance.test-ec2deployment.id
}

resource "aws_eip" "example" {
  vpc = true
}
```

Above is the main file and i'm loading the following module:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "my-webserver" {
  name        = "webserver"
  description = "Allow HTTP from Anywhere"
  vpc_id      = "vpc-"
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "my-webserver"
    Site = "my-web-site"
  }
}
```

The last step is attaching the security group to the machine but again, no clue on how to do that. I've been reading several docs and tried to google but I cannot seem to find the answer or the answer does not work for me. So hopefully you guys can help me further.

Thanks for your time, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In aws_security_group module you need to output security group id by add the following in ./modules/services/Security groups//main.tf

```
output "securitygroup_id" {
  value = aws_security_group.my-webserver.id
}
```

then in your main tf file attach security group to your instance like this:

```
resource "aws_network_interface_sg_attachment" "sg_attachment" {
  security_group_id    = module.aws_security_group.securitygroup_id
  network_interface_id = aws_instance.test-ec2deployment.primary_network_interface_id
}
```

Comment: THAT'S IT! Thanks you very much! Now i will try to understand this part but atleast i can proceed now instead of being stuck. Thanks again!